# define a function to search for a specific word in a text file and print total lines

Tags: python, python-3.7

I need help with my code. I am trying to define a function that will search for a specific word in a text file and then print out all the lines with the give word and the total of times the word appears in the text file.

```
def read_words(fname):
    fin = open(fname)
    es_count = 0
    for w in fin:
        word=w
        if " " in word:
            es_count = es_count + 1
            print(word)
```

The output needs to show the words and the total count.
For example: words in text file that have OG in them.

correct output needed:

```
dog
fog
jog
hog
the total number of words: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def read_word(fname, word):
    fin = open(fname)
    founds = []
    for line in fin.readlines():
        if word in line:
            founds.append(line)
    print('\n'.join(founds))
    print('the total number of words: %d' % len(founds))


read_word(fname='file.txt', word='og')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the input function. for example if the user wants words that start with Ch. how would I include that?

Comment: The you should change the `if word in line` part to `if line.startswith(word)` .